# How to minimize a maximum of a linear combination?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

When reading [this note](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee392o/cvxccv.pdf), I encounter the following linear programming problem(Equation 6 in the note)

$$
\begin{align}
\text{minimize}\quad&t\\
\text{s.t.}\quad& \pmb u\ge\pmb 0\\
&\pmb 1^\top\pmb u=1\\
&P^\top\pmb u\le t\pmb 1
\end{align}
$$

I'm wondering how to approach this problem. For example, when $P$ is a matrix below(Equation 10 in the note)
[image]

the optimal solution to the problem(Equation 11 in the note) is

$$
\pmb u=\begin{bmatrix}0.486&0.077& 0&0&0&0&0.104&0.035&0.298&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$

I've read [this tutorial](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Edenisp/csc373/docs/tutorial6-reg.pdf) and get a basic sense of how to approach such problems. But it deals with non-vectors and introduces some slack variables so as to replace all constrained variables in the objective with the slack variables. Does it mean that I should expand the above matrix and vectors and doing something similar?

Comment: To find an optimal $u$, call a linear programming solver.

Comment: Hi @RobPratt. I'm not aware of any linear programming solver, couldn't it be done by hand?

Comment: In principle, yes, but I wouldn’t want to do anything by hand with an $11\times 11$ matrix.

Comment: I agree. But I'm wondering about the method. The tutorial I referred to in the question introduces some slack variables and replaces all constrained variables in the objective with those slack variables. Is this the standard way to approach these problems? If it is, can I do the same using matrix/vector operations?

Comment: Yes, that tutorial is illustrating the [simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm).